# How do I calculate this gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, expected-value, gaussian-integral

I am asked to find the expectation of the greater of X and Y where X and Y are normal bivariates with zero individual means and unit variance with correlation coefficient $\rho$.
I know the answer is just
$$2\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}y\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{(x^{2}+y^{2}-2xy\rho)}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$ .
But how do I calculate this Gaussian integral?.
I have tried adding and substracting $x\rho$ so that the integral in terms of y can be calculated but then I run into another integral where the integral in terms of y is of the form $\int \exp(-y^{2})\mathrm{d}y$ . Which has no antiderivative.
I tried polar coordinates but it resulted in a really tough trigonometric integral.

Comment: This looks like a good time for polar coordinates.

Comment: Did you try polar coordinates?

Comment: No I did not think of polar coordinates. I'LL try it now.

Comment: I tried polar coordinates but I am getting a really tough trigonometric integral.

Comment: You can edit your attempt into the question.

Comment: We meant edit the actual work you put into the polar coordinates attempt, not the description of it

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\sigma \equiv \root{1 - \rho^{2}}}$ and
$\ds{{\pars{x,y} \over \root{2}\sigma} \mapsto \pars{x,y}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over \pi\root{1 - \rho^{2}}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}y\,
\exp\pars{-{x^{2} + y^{2} -2xy\rho \over
2\pars{1 -\rho^{2}}}}\,\dd y\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2\root{2}\sigma^{2} \over \pi}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\int_{\root{2}\sigma x}^{\infty}y\,
\expo{-x^{2} - y^{2} + 2\rho xy}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{4 \over \pi^{3/2}}\,
{\pars{1 - \rho^{2}}\pars{1 - \root{2}\rho\root{1 - \rho^{2}}} \over \root{3 - 2\rho\pars{\rho + \root{2}\root{1 - \rho^{2}}}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
with $\ds{\root{2}\root{1 - \rho^{2}} < \rho < 1}$.
(\ref{1}) was found with some CAS.